# jquery mobile: how to prevent the header row of a list view from getting filtered out

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I am creating a jquery mobile listview that can be filtered on it's content like below:

```
<ul data-filter="true" ...>
<li class='thisrowshouldnotbefilteredout'></li>
<li>content to filter on</li>
......
......
</ul>
```

The first row is my header and I don't want it to hide when user enters text to filter on. Is there an attribute I can give to this row, or will I have to override the base call back function for fitering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override filter logic like this:

```
$("#mylist").listview('option', 'filterCallback', customSearch);

var customSearch = function(text, searchValue, item) {
    return text.toLowerCase().indexOf( searchValue) === -1;
}
```

Any function defined for the callback will be provided three arguments. First, the text of the current list item, second the value being searched for, and third the list item being filtered. A truthy value will result in a hidden list item. The default callback which filters entries without the searchValue as a substring is described below.

Use it to skip your header li element. Modify it as you wish.

Example and more about this can be found here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/docs-lists.html

Comment: I was hoping they would have some stuff in place to skip the headers by default. Some magic data attribute that I wasn't aware of! Guess this would be the only route. Thanks for the refresher on the call back.

Comment: No problem m8, I am glad to help.

Comment: @Gajotres no idea why you said "Any function defined for the callback will be provided three arguments" while the jQM API said "The function accepts two arguments" ref: http://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/#option-filterCallback

Answer (score 1):

Another route that I took was to actually change one line in the jQuery Mobile code.

Line 6846 in jquery.mobile.1-3.1.js

```
listItems = list.children( ":not(.ui-screen-hidden)" );
```

to

```
listItems = list.children( ":not(.ui-screen-hidden):not(.no-filter)" );
```

Then just add the class "no-filter" to whatever items you don't want to be filtered.

You could of course use different logic other than a class, such as never filtering the first child, or using a data-no-filter="true" attribute.

I would say that a custom callback is clearly the preferred method, since this would break if you had to re-install jQuery mobile, but since we won't be doing this was a really quick solution.

Comment: If it didn't involve overwriting the jQuery lib, this is a pretty good solution.

Comment: I agree.  In our use case we heavily modified jQuery mobile to begin with, so making these modifications isn't a deal breaker.

Answer (score 0):

You can add code like this to add support for a "data-no-filter" attribute:

```
var origFilter = $.mobile.filterable.prototype.options.filterCallback;
  $.mobile.filterable.prototype.options.filterCallback = function(index, searchValue) {
    var origVal = origFilter.apply(this, arguments);

    if ($(this).attr('data-no-filter') === 'true') {
      return false;
    } else {
      return origVal;
    }
}
```

Then, in your HTML you can prevent items from getting filtered by setting data-no-filter="true" on the element.